# Problema con proyecto laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema con un proyecto de laravel. La pagina web en el servidor local funcionaba todo correctamente a la hora de crear usuarios, crear recetas, ver los perfiles, etc.

El problema ha venido al subirla al servidor web. La pagina en principio funciona bien, se puede registrar usuarios, El problema llega cuando quiero incluir nuevas recetas, cuando le doy a enviar la receta para que la registre en la base de datos me da el error 500. Llegué a pensar la comunicación con la base de datos no es buena, pero si exporto la base de datos creada en mi servidor local, las recetas se ven correctamente en la pagina, lo que quiere decir que tiene conexión con la base de datos. Solo tengo problemas para insertar nuevas recetas. La verdad que no se me ocurre nada. Si alguien pudiera echarme una mano, lo agradecería mucho.

El error que aparece en el log es el siguiente.

[2021-04-17 12:51:17] production.ERROR: Image source not readable {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException(code: 0): Image source not readable at /home/ine7lacoc/recetaslaravel/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:346) [stacktrace]

Aqui adjunto el Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\CategoriaReceta;
use App\Receta;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class RecetaController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['show', 'search']]);
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

      

        $usuario = auth()->user();

        // Recetas con paginación
        $recetas = Receta::where('user_id', $usuario->id)->paginate(10);

        
        return view('recetas.index')
            ->with('recetas', $recetas)
            ->with('usuario', $usuario);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
       
        // Con modelo
        $categorias = CategoriaReceta::all(['id', 'nombre']);

        return view('recetas.create')->with('categorias', $categorias);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        


        // validación
        $data = $request->validate([
            'titulo' => 'required|min:6',
            'preparacion' => 'required',
            'ingredientes' => 'required',
            'imagen' => 'required|image',
            'categoria' => 'required',
        ]);

        // obtener la ruta de la imagen
        $ruta_imagen = $request['imagen']->store('upload-recetas', 'public');

        // Resize de la imagen
        $img = Image::make( public_path("storage/{$ruta_imagen}"))->fit(1000, 550);
        $img->save();

        // almacenar en la BD (con modelo)
        auth()->user()->recetas()->create([
             'titulo' => $data['titulo'],
             'preparacion' => $data['preparacion'],
             'ingredientes' => $data['ingredientes'],
             'imagen' => $ruta_imagen,
             'categoria_id' => $data['categoria']
        ]);



        // Redireccionar
        return redirect()->action('RecetaController@index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Receta  $receta
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Receta $receta)
    {
        // Obtener si el usuario actual le gusta la receta y esta autenticado
        $like = ( auth()->user() ) ?  auth()->user()->meGusta->contains($receta->id) : false; 

        // Pasa la cantidad de likes a la vista
        $likes = $receta->likes->count();

        return view('recetas.show', compact('receta', 'like', 'likes'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Receta  $receta
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Receta $receta)
    {
        // Revisar el policy
        $this->authorize('view', $receta);

        // Con modelo
        $categorias = CategoriaReceta::all(['id', 'nombre']);

        return view('recetas.edit', compact('categorias', 'receta'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Receta  $receta
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Receta $receta)
    {

        // Revisar el policy
        $this->authorize('update', $receta);

        // validación
        $data = $request->validate([
            'titulo' => 'required|min:6',
            'preparacion' => 'required',
            'ingredientes' => 'required',
            'categoria' => 'required',
        ]);

        // Asignar los valores
        $receta->titulo = $data['titulo'];
        $receta->preparacion = $data['preparacion'];
        $receta->ingredientes = $data['ingredientes'];
        $receta->categoria_id = $data['categoria'];


        // Si el usuario sube una nueva imagen
        if(request('imagen')) {
            // obtener la ruta de la imagen
            $ruta_imagen = $request['imagen']->store('upload-recetas', 'public');

            // Resize de la imagen
            $img = Image::make( public_path("storage/{$ruta_imagen}"))->fit(1000, 550);
            $img->save();

            // Asignar al objeto
            $receta->imagen = $ruta_imagen;
        }

        $receta->save();

        // redireccionar
        return redirect()->action('RecetaController@index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Receta  $receta
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Receta $receta)
    {
        // Ejecutar el Policy
        $this->authorize('delete', $receta);

        // Eliminar la receta
        $receta->delete();

        return redirect()->action('RecetaController@index');
    }

    public function search(Request $request) 
    {
        // $busqueda = $request['buscar'];
        $busqueda = $request->get('buscar');

        $recetas = Receta::where('titulo', 'like', '%' . $busqueda . '%')->paginate(10);
        $recetas->appends(['buscar' => $busqueda]);

        return view('busquedas.show', compact('recetas', 'busqueda'));
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias saludos

Comment: [2021-04-17 12:51:17] production.ERROR: Image source not readable {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException(code: 0): Image source not readable at /home/ine7lacoc/recetaslaravel/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:346)
[stacktrace]  Este seria la primera linea del error. Muchas gracias por contestar

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Estás subiendo imágenes en tu formulario, o estás haciendo una inserción de una imagen?

Comment: Hago una inserción  de una imagen. Y aparte el envio de un formulario con cada apartado independiente.

Comment: Mi pregunta es porque funciona todo en mi servidor local y me esta danto todo estos problemas en el servidor compartido.

Comment: esta botando exception el interventionImage porque no encuentra el recurso que debe modificar, por lo que veo estas enviando los archivos al storage, ya tienes creado el enlace simbolico?

Comment: En mi servidor local con la terminal lo cree php artisan storage:link. Pero en el cpanel no puedo utilizar la terminal entonces no se como poder crear ese enlace simbólico.

Comment: @BetaM eso que me comentas como lo haría ?? ahi me pierdo totalmente

Comment: Comparte el formulario tal vez ahí tengas un error de sintáxis.

Comment: si no tienes el enlace simbolico es imposible acceder al recurso, como en cpanel no tienes acceso a ssh podrias general el enlace colocando la rutina en alguna ruta

Comment: Si en la carpeta routes en el  archivo web.php que es donde tengo todos los route. Añado esta linea.
Route::get('/storage-link', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
Debería de funcionar o me faltaría algo mas??

Comment: He probado todo y no puedo o no sé solucionarlo. Me esta volviendo loco esto de crear el enlace simbólico.